# Installing packages from 16.10 repo while on 16.04?

Tags: apt, 16.04, repository, 16.10

Apologies if the title is a bit obtuse.

Essentially I'd like to use the [mingw-w64 package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=mingw-w64) version 4.0.6. Unfortunately I'm on 16.04 and the package for this version of Ubuntu is currently at 4.0.4.

The package for 16.10 is at the latest version of mingw-w64. Is there a way I can update my current packages to use the 16.10 repo, or would that be a bad idea? Or is there another way I can get the 4.0.6 package?

Thanks for any help :-)

Comment: You can download just that .deb package from that page by clicking on "yakkety" -- here's the direct link: http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/all/mingw-w64/download

Comment: If it installs without pulling in other dependencies or upgrading other packages, it should be fine

Comment: Oh awesome, thank you very much! So I've tried installing it with the software installer, but the version remains at 4.0.4, even after a reboot. I'm guessing that might be on purpose? Would you recommend I try on a clean install? Also there are dependencies that are needed, will they get updated as well automatically or should I install one by one?